# Code to print files in a directory along with its content

Tags: perl

The below mentioned is throwing the following error upon execution-:

```
Global symbol "@files" requires explicit package name at ./q1.pl line 6.
Global symbol "$i" requires explicit package name at ./q1.pl line 6.
Global symbol "@files" requires explicit package name at ./q1.pl line 17.
```

Can someone explain me how to mitigate this problem and help me to optimize the code further

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

sub print_file {
    open FILE, $files[$i];
    while(my $line = <FILE>) {
        print $line;
    }
}

sub globdir {
    my $dir = shift;
    @files = glob "$dir/*";
    $i = 0;
    while($i <= $#files) {
        print("Files in the directory $files[$i] \n");
        $i++;
        print_file $files;
    }
}

globdir @ARGV;
```

Comment: http://perlmaven.com/variable-declaration-in-perl

Comment: If you use the diamond operator, you can open and read the files in the directory with a `while (<>)` loop. This is what the `-p` switch does, so basically your program can be reduced to `perl -pe0 dir/*`, if your shell supports globbing arguments. Try adding the switch `-MO=Deparse` to see how the underlying code looks.

Comment: You asked Perl to remind you when you forgot to declare your variables using `use strict;`, and it obliged. Found some serious errors too. Too many for me to go into details right now, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You should include [`use strict;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html) and [`use warnings;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html) at the top of EVERY perl script like you've done here.

One of the things that this will tell you is when you've failed to declare a variable with [`my`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/my.html), which will assist you in avoiding simple spelling errors in your code.

Error:

```
Global symbol "@files" requires explicit package name at ./q1.pl line 6.
```

Fix by declaring the variable:

```
my @files = glob "$dir/*";
```

That should be enough information for you to fix the other errors in your code.  However, I would like to recommend that you simplify your code to just the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

my $dir = shift;

for my $file (<$dir/*>) {
    print "File in the directory: $file\n";

    # Output File Contents:
    open my $fh, '<', $file;
    print <$fh>;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you include the line `use strict` Perl tells you about variables which you're using, but not declaring. The error about `$i` is because you're using the variable `$i` without declaring it. By changing the `$i` to `my $i` the first time you use it, you'll be OK.

```
$i = 0;
```

becomes

```
my $i = 0;
```

With `@files` it's more complicated. You're using it in both functions `print_file` and `globdir`. To do this, you'll need to put a:

```
my @lines;
```

before the first function. But you probably don't want to do this. You're trying to pass the filename to `print_file` as an argument, but not using it. To get the filename you're passing, in the code fore `print_file` put:

```
my $filename = shift;
```

So you then get:

```
sub print_file {
    my $filename = shift;
    open FILE, $filename;
    while(my $line = <FILE>) {
        print $line;
    }
}
```

and you don't need `@files` in `print_file`. But you also need to call the `print_file` function with the name of the file, so you'll need:

```
print_file $files[$i];
```

and you'll need to put a `my` before `@files'.

So we now have:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

sub print_file {
    my $filename = shift;
    open FILE, $filename;
    while(my $line = <FILE>) {
        print $line;
    }
}

sub globdir {
    my $dir = shift;
    my @files = glob "$dir/*";
    my $i = 0;
    while($i <= $#files) {
        print("Files in the directory $files[$i] \n");
        $i++;
        print_file $files[$i];
    }
}

globdir @ARGV;
```

At the very least, this now runs, and does something close to what you want it to. There are quite a few more problems with it. See how you can improve it, and then ask here if you need any further help.

---

For the record, I'd probably tackle this problem something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

sub print_file {
  my $filename = shift;
  if (open my $fh, '<', $filename) {
    local $/;
    print <$fh>;
  }
}

sub globdir {
  foreach my $dir (@_) {
    foreach my $filename (glob "$dir/*") {
      print "Contents of file $filename:\n";
      print_file $filename;
      print "\n";
    }
  }
}

globdir @ARGV;
```

If you read this through and understand how and why it's different from your answer, you'll probably learn quite a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Try it. This is also print the file name with its contents.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
my $dir ='Direcotry_name';
opendir("dir",$dir); 
my @files = grep{m/.*\.txt/g} readdir("dir");  
foreach (@files){
    print "Filename is: $_";
    open("file","$dir/$_");
    my @ar = <file>;
    print "@ar";
}
```

In this code line 4 regexp `m/.*\.txt/` get the particular format file into the directory.